# openpyxl conditional row formatting is off by one row

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working in openpyxl on highlighting an entire excel row if a single column has the value "I don't live in the United States". Here's what I have so far:

```
yellow_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="ffff00")
dxf = DifferentialStyle(fill=yellow_fill)
r = Rule(type="expression", dxf=dxf, stopIfTrue=True)
r.formula = ['$Q2="I don\'t live in the United States"']
ws.conditional_formatting.add("A1:AA500", r)
```

Luckily, the formatting is accurate on the how many rows to highlight and how far spaced out they are, but my header is getting highlighted and it looks like the highlighting is actually moved up a row for the entire format, [image for example of what it produces on dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb6Mo.png). I'm not sure why the formatting is moved up from the actual data it is conditionally formatting on, and am happy to clarify more if needed, but basically I want the highlighted rows to line up with my actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I just needed to adjust the r.formula to $Q1 instead of $Q2. I was trying to avoid using the header but it shifted all the conditional formatting up one row for some reason.